# Adding items to a list based on a reference to parent item

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List` of the same type `Parcel`.

```
public class Parcel
{
 int Id {get;set;}
 int RecipientID {get;set;}
 DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
}

List<Parcel> aparcels = postFacade.GetParcels()
                               .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn);

List<Parcel> bparcels = postFacade.GetReplyParcels();
```

The `Parcel` objects from `aparcels` are top-level items. Their `RecipientID` is never another `Parcel` Id.

The `Parcel` objects from `bparcels` are replies to `Parcel` objects in `aparcel`. Their `RecipientID` is always a `Parcel` Id. However `bparcels` contains objects **all** replying `Parcel` objects, not just for the list of `Parcel` objects in `aparcel`.

I want to create a new list of `Parcel` objects from `aparcels` sorted by `CreatedOn`.

However if a `Parcel` from `aparcels` is referenced by a `Parcel` from `bparcels`(via `RecipientID`) I want to add the corresponding `Parcel` from `bparcels` after the `Parcel` from `aparcel` in the list.

I then want to check `bparcels` for any other `Parcel` objects that reference the "replying" `Parcel` and add it to the list, checking `bparcels` recursively until no more "reply" `Parcel` objects are found.

This is what I've come up with:

```
        List<Parcel> parcels = new List<Parcels>();
        var replies = bposts.ToDictionary(u => u.RecipientID, p => p.Id);
        foreach (var p in aparcels)
        {
            parcels.Add(p);
            int commid = p.Id;
            int val;
            while (replies.TryGetValue(commid, out val))
            {
                parcels.Add(parcelFacade.GetById(val));
                commid = val;
            }
        }
```

Is there any way I can increase the performance of this operation? It will potentially be dealing with hundreds/thousands of `Parcel` objects.

Comment: Does this even work?  It sounds like multiple `replies` can have the same `Id` which would cause a `DuplicateKeyException` in the dictionary.

Comment: Could you change your naming conventions to make it easier to understand? Also, how does a `Reply` references another `Reply`, `RecipientID` == `Id`?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Each `Id` is unique since they are all `Parcel` objects. Each `Parcel` that "replies" to another parcel references the unique ID of the `Parcel` it is "responding" to with `RecipientID`. It's basically a crude linked list that I am trying to follow to determine insertion order

Comment: @AndreCalil Sorry it's a bit confusing, all the objects are the same `Parcel` object but have some other properties that differentiate them in my code(and when I'm making the lists). I'll try to reword it. And yes each `Reply` has a `RecipientID` == `Id` of another `Reply`, or in the case of the parent `Parcel` `RecipientID` == `Id` of `Post`

Comment: I actually think what you have here should perform pretty well - do you have specific performance numbers that indicate a problem?

Comment: The problem here is calling parcelFacade.GetById(val) every time even though all the reply parcels were already loaded, since the data is probably in a different machine/process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should store a reference to the Parcels themselves in the dictionary, which are already in the list so you don't have to load them again from you Facade, which is probably what is slowing down your code.

```
    List<Parcel> parcels = new List<Parcels>();
    var replies = bposts.ToDictionary(u => u.RecipientID);
    foreach (var p in aparcels)
    {
        parcels.Add(p);
        Parcel parent = p;

        while (replies.TryGetValue(parent.Id, out parent))
        {
            parcels.Add(parent);
        }
    }
```

Or, to make it even shorter:

```
    foreach (var p in aparcels)
    {
        var current = p;
        do parcels.Add(current);
        while (replies.TryGetValue(current.Id, out current));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things a bit.

You can do a simple loop through the original posts collection, and add in what you need easily by using:

```
foreach(var a in aposts.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedOn))
{
    parcels.Add(a);
    parcels.Add(bposts.Where(b => a.ID == b.RecipientID).OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedOn));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Taking into account the fact that you want to loop through each bpost reply to get any other replies to it, I've written an iteration method that will loop until all parent -> children -> grandchildren -> etc. are resolved. This should get everything you want based upon created on field.

```
foreach(var a in aposts.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedOn))
{
    parcels.Add(a);
    foreach(var b in bposts.Where(bpost => bpost.RecipientID == a.ID).OrderByDescending(bpost => bpost.CreatedOn))
    {
        parcels.AddRange(Iterate(b, bposts));
    }
}

public IList<Parcel> Iterate(Parcel a, IList<Parcel> b)
{
    var parcels = new List<Parcel>();
    foreach(var post in b.Where(bpost => a.ID == bpost.RecipientID).OrderByDescending(bpost => bpost.CreatedOn))
    {
        parcels.Add(post);
        parcels.AddRange(Iterate(post, b));
    }
    return parcels;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the conditions of ordering or recursively adding replying `Parcel` objects. A reply `Parcel` may not have been created immediately after its parent -- the creation date is arbitrary. Also a reply `Parcel` may have another `Parcel` replying to it, etc. etc. I need to get all replies and add them to the list

Comment: So you're looking for an infinity loop to run over the replies to ensure that every reply that may have replies of it's own get added?

Like a "Comments" section. I can comment on your main post, then someone can comment on my comment, and then someone else can comment on their comment, etc.

Ok, got it.